# How to create an application that detect and measures the gas percentage in a specific area?

Tags: android

Once I receive the gas percentage from the Arduino board I check this percentage, if high the application will send an SMS with the current location.
the problem is that as long as the percentage is high the application keep sending the sms message infinitely until the percentage back to it's normal state!

I guess that the problem can be solved by creating a timer but I'm not so sure of how will it be implemented.

also not sure of how to create a method that return the current location?

Comment: Post the code which you have already tried and describe the problem you are facing more clearly. Please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Set a boolean flag that identifies whether an sms has already been sent. Reset this once the percentage falls below the specified level.

Answer (score 0):

There's two common ways to do this. The first method is simply using a boolean variable to state if you've sent an SMS or not. Set it to `True` when you send an SMS, and then set it to `False` once your gas level goes back below your threshold.

There's a large drawback to this: If your gas sensor hovers around the threshold (rising above it and then dipping back down repeatedly), your SMS code may be triggered multiple times. To avoid this you can use the second method: store the timestamp of when the last SMS was sent and avoid sending again within the set time period.

If you use method two alone, you will receive constant notifications whenever the time period is up (if the gas level is over the threshold), but if you combine it with method one you should only receive 1 message every `x` minutes and only when the gas level first rises above the threshold.

Comment: Thanks you very much  :)